# Wait until collection in package is available

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, atmosphere.js

I'm currently developing a Meteor package where I want to insert some data into a Meteor collection which is available in the "core"-Application where the package is added to.

One thing I want to do is to insert some data into a collection on Startup:

```
# Inside the package (the Books-Collection is a collection form the core-App)
Meteor.startup ->
  Books.insert title: 'foo', author: 'bar'
```

This doesn't work because the package gets loaded first. Therefore the Books-Collection from the core-System is not available. It works as expected if I encapsulate it into a function which I can call later.

```
# inside the package (the Books-Collection is a collection form the core-App)
sampleFunction = ->
  Books.insert title: 'foo', author: 'bar'

# call function e.g. after 10 seconds
sampleFunction()
```

I could enter the call to the function in the core-Application but I would like to encapsulate this functionality inside the package so everytime the user adds the package a book is automatically inserted.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is likely because your collection is being defined in a `Meteor.startup`. If you define it on its own it should work as you expect it to:

```
Books = new (Mongo.Collection)('books')
```

Instead of:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Books = new (Mongo.Collection)('books')
```

Second it's not possible to run code when a package is added in a way where you can access your app's collections information.

The best you can do is run the code every time the app is run (such as the first time the app is run after the package is added):

You can check if the book is already added and if not add it in:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Books.upsert { title: 'foo' },
    title: 'foo'
    author: 'bar'
```

The above all works best on the server.